# What is the disease of cucumber leaf?

Tags: identification, diseases, cucumbers

I want to share some pictures of the cucumber leaf. I have no idea.
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Several days ago, there were some white spots. I uses some soda power water. But now it is totally yellow.